# ajaxfileupload OnUploadCompleteAll not work

Tags: c#, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ASP.Net AJAX control toolkit ajaxfileupload.
I would like to show a message box and refresh the web page when all files were uploaded.

Hence, i implemented 'OnUploadCompleteAll' in server side, and set a break point for this event.

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload_UploadCompleteAll(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
{
    //Method 1
    Response.Redirect("someWhere.aspx");

    //Method2
    string str_AlertMessage = "";
    str_AlertMessage = "alert('Upload finished.');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), str_AlertMessage, str_AlertMessage, true);
    return;
}
```

Although the program can run into this event, no matter I use either method 1 or method 2, it cannot redirect to another page or show any alert.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I think your should do it via javascript. It's better solution.

Comment: Oh thanks. I use javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to show alert box than only you have to redirect your page. If your are directing first and than you are showing alert message than it wont work properly.
Now in this below given code..First alert message will displayed. and when you click on "ok" of "alertbox" than only you will redirect.
Try this below given..and vote if you like this answer.

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload_UploadCompleteAll(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadCompleteAllEventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('File Upload Finished');", true);

   Response.Redirect("someWhere.aspx");
}
```